# SAS how to use first. with NOTSORTED

Tags: sas

I am having this issue

My code is

```
data step10;
  set step9;
  by referenceid NOTSORTED;
  if first.referenceid then JOIN_KEY=1;
  ELSE JOIN_KEY+1;
run;
```

Then output showing

[image]

This last two rows should be 2, since "MBA1" AND "MBA2" are already exists before.

Except these two rows should be 1, since it is unique.

How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A by-group is the sequence of rows that are adjacent, having the same by-var values.

`NOTSORTED` is for processing groups constructed from by values that are **contiguous** yet not sorted.

All your sample data has by-groups of size 1 because none of the id values are repeated looking down the column.

Here are two techniques you can try:

- sort the data by `referenceid` and `<some-other-sequencing-variable>` and do normal by group processing.
- maintain a hash of `referenceid` and *hit-counts* as you process the data set

**Hash example** (my `sequenceId` === your `join_key`):

```
data want;
  set have;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash ids();
    ids.defineKey('referenceid');
    ids.defineData('referenceid', 'sequenceId');
    ids.defineDone();
  end;

  if ids.find() ne 0 
    then sequenceId = 1;
    else sequenceId + 1;

  ids.replace();
run;
```